# How to substract a SimpleDateFormat and a String

Tags: java, date-format

This Dateclass handles the age of each members and calculate the persons age by getting his birthday. Then we get actual date and substract it with birthday.

My problem is that a can't substract a SimpleDateFormat and a String. How can I fix this problem?

```
Date dt = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy");
System.out.print(sdf.format(dt));

ArrayList<String> Mem = Data.getCpr();
String newStr = Mem.toString();
```

This is a birthday we wish to use to substract

```
String birth = newStr.substring(1, 7);
System.out.print(" "+birth);
```

This is the substraction of a SimpleDateFormat and a String

```
int age = sdf - birth;
```

Comment: Tip: Subtract the dates and not their String representations.

Comment: This is my output: 060514 199902

Comment: The first one is actuel date and second is birth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class, instantiate one using the current time, and the other using the members birthday, then use the `add` method to figure out the age.  Remember that you will have to compare the month and day as well otherwise you will end up just with the `age` this year rather than the members real age.